# Storing Data in Java

Tags: java, memory

I'm currently trying to write a simple journal-like program in Java that allows me to add "entries" and be able to browse all the "entries" I have added since the very beginning. The problem is, if I run the program, add two entries, exit the program, and then run the program again, I want to be able to have access to the two entries I previously added. I guess my questions is then, how am I able to "save" (if that's the right word) the entries that I add so that they won't be wiped out every time the program terminates?

I did some looking around, and it appears there's a tool I can use called the Java Cache System, but I'm not entirely sure if that's what I need for my situation. I'd appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Why not save them to a file and when you open the program retrieve data from the file?

Comment: Caching is not what you want; you want *persistence* instead, which is about saving data between program runs. If using a file browser is okay, it's probably easiest just to save all of your entries in a directory as text files. Otherwise, you'll need some form of database to save your entries in. This can be a bit tricky to do by hand, but if you're willing to let your program *include* external libraries, you can use a persistence tool to handle the nuts and bolts.

Comment: As a note, I recommend against using a Java serialization of your whole `List` or other data structure; it'll get long quickly, and you'll have to read/write the entire thing every time you load or save.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the program and create the entries your storing them in primary storage aka RAM.  As you have discovered these entries will not persist across different executions of your program.

You need to store the entries in secondary storage aka the hard drive.  This can be done by writing the entries to a file saved on disk and then reading those entries upon startup of the program.  Java provides several mechanisms to read and write files to the file system on a machine.

Some applications use a database to store information in a relational manner so that it is available via a SQL request, however I would recommend using a simple file to store your entries.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to store this data somehow in a file, and then read it from the file when the application starts, a few simple examples on how to write/read from file:

http://www2.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/MyFileReader.java

http://www2.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/MyFileReader.txt

http://www2.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/MyFileWriter.java

http://www2.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/MyFileWriter.txt

Answer (score 0):

Now, you store your objects in memory instead of this you can try to serialize them to some format like xml. And then in next run load them from xml. Or you can try to use dataBase for storing objects.

Comment: In this case, plain text is probably just fine, and a lot less hassle to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem in past but little bit different.I clearly understood your problem , My solution is whatever the journal you are entering and getting saved should be saved in a particular location in your Location such as "C:\Your_Directory\Journal_folder\"

so it will be easier when you initially enter the journal it stores in above location ,again if u exit and reopen the application just try to retrieve the data from the above Mentioned target Location.

therefore every time when ever you enter the application it retrieves the data from that location if not it displays empty

Comment: I dont think this is his problem, from what I understands he does not understand why his program does not save the state by default.